# restrictions of closed linear operator to range of its powers

Tags: operator-theory, linear-transformations

I am trying to prove that if $T$ is a closed densely defined operator on a Hilbert space(or Banach space), $\lambda$ is non-zero and $T_n$ is the restriction of T to range $R(T^n)$ for some n, then:
(i) $N((T_n - \lambda I)^m) = N((T - \lambda I)^m)$ for any m
(ii) $R((T_n - \lambda I)^m) = R((T - \lambda I)^m) \cap R(T^n)$ for any m
(iii) dimension of $N(T_n - \lambda I)$ = dimension of $N(T - \lambda I)$
(iv) codimension of $R(T_n - \lambda I)$ = codimension of $R(T - \lambda I)$

This fact was proved for bounded linear operators in http://www.eweb.unex.es/eweb/extracta/Vol-28-1/28B1Carp.pdf

Is that even possible when we have operators that are not everywhere defined?